# How to invoke 'not' in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex to find a pattern, that should exclude some stuff. For this example, 
"i am  from i am text text text text i am from Japan text text John from Canada text I am mr john doe from test test test I am ..."

the expression should hit only 'John from', or 'mr john doe from' but exclude 'i am from'

I have tried this,

```
re.findall(r"(?!i am from)((?:miss|mister|mr)*(?:\s*\w+\s+){1,2})from", "i am  from i am text text text text i am from Japan text text John from I am mr john doe  from test test test I am"  )
```

But it also hits, on 'i am'

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest match to what you expect comes from a regex like this:

```
(?:\b(?:mis(?:tre|s)|mr)\s+)?((?:\b(?!(?:i|am|from)\b)\w+\s+){1,2})from
```

in which you are able to exclude words to be matched right after a `from`. Here exclusion is done by a negative lookahead:

```
(?!(?:i|am|from)\b)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/XO3eWj/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only exclude "i am from" that is correct. "i am" (not followed by "from") is not "i am from".

Otherwise just use "i am" for the negative look-ahead.